# Check if cell value is empty for specific columns and if true put some data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, validation, openpyxl

Lets say i have an Excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I am using openpyxl to write some data validation in the cells that are empty. But to apply that, I need to check if the cells from column C to D have values and if not I want to populate the cells with some data validation.

Any idea how can I get for example the output that C3, C4, D3, D4, E3, E4, F3, F4 are empty so i can use then to validate the cells.

This is the code i will be using to add data validation, and that is why i need for example C3:

```
data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='=$E$3:$R$3') 
ws.add_data_validation(data_val)
data_val.add(ws["C3"])
```

Comment: So you want to know if `ws["C3"]` is empty?

Comment: Actually I want to know all the cells that are empty for columns C, D, E, F.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer that i was looking for, so this is the code i will be using if anyone needs it:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
import re

path=r'...'
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

ws = wb.active

#for Column C
for row in range(ws.max_row):
    for column in "C":
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row+1)
        value= ws[cell_name].value
        if value is None:
           k=re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', cell_name)
           data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1=''=$E${0}:$R${1}')'.format(k[1],k[1])) 
           ws.add_data_validation(data_val)
           data_val.add(ws[cell_name]) 


wb.save()
```